# How to extract href in sub-tags through BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

For example:

```
<ul class="polysemantList-wrapper cmn-clearfix" style="display: none">
<li class="item">▪<span class="selected">美国1995年马丁·坎贝尔执导好莱坞电影</span></li>
<li class="item">▪<a title="锦瑟华年创作都市异能小说" href="/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/7822656#viewPageContent">锦瑟华年创作都市异能小说</a></li>
<li class="item">▪<a title="单兵便携式电脑" href="/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/16402442#viewPageContent">单兵便携式电脑</a></li>
<li class="item">▪<a title="任天堂Wii主机射击类游戏《黄金眼》" href="/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/9585407#viewPageContent">任天堂Wii主机射击类游戏《黄金眼》</a></li>
<li class="item">▪<a title="珠宝鉴定职业" href="/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/9585395#viewPageContent">珠宝鉴定职业</a></li>
<li class="item">▪<a title="Rare Software制作的N64游戏" href="/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/10704458#viewPageContent">Rare Software制作的N64游戏</a></li>
<li class="item">▪<a title="大鹏金翅明王小说" href="/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/17571741#viewPageContent">大鹏金翅明王小说</a></li>
<li class="item">▪<a title="证券分析软件" href="/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/9585420#viewPageContent">证券分析软件</a></li>
<li class="item">▪<a title="《藏地密码》中的藏獒" href="/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/9585384#viewPageContent">《藏地密码》中的藏獒</a></li>
</ul>
```

First, I can extract the multi items:

```
multi_entry = soup.findAll('ul', attrs = {'class': 'polysemantList-wrapper cmn-clearfix'})
```

Then how to navigate to the href of the sub tag li? I want to get a list of all the urls in each item. The following can extract all 'li' items, but it is not necessarily from the polysemantList section.

```
li_items = soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class': 'item'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find all the `li` with a class of `item` in `polysemantList-wrapper cmn-clearfix` with one search. Then we can iterate over the result and output the `href` values.

```
li = soup.find("ul", { "class" : "polysemantList-wrapper cmn-clearfix" }).findAll("li", attrs={'class': 'item'}, recursive=False)

for e in li:
    for x in e.findAll('a', href=True):
        print(x['href'])
```

Could also output a list using list comprehension

```
[x['href'] for e in li for x in e.findAll('a', href=True)]
```

Output

---

```
/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/7822656#viewPageContent
/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/16402442#viewPageContent
/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/9585407#viewPageContent
/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/9585395#viewPageContent
/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/10704458#viewPageContent
/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/17571741#viewPageContent
/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/9585420#viewPageContent
/item/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E7%9C%BC/9585384#viewPageContent
```